# How can I save grouped counts across factor levels into a new variable with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, count

i try to save grouped counts of various factor levels into a new variable:

Lets say my data look like this:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
b <- c("acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con","acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej")

df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

The resulting data frame should look like this:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
number_acc <- c(2,2,1,2)
number_rej <- c(2,1,2,2)
number_con <- c(1,2,2,1)
```

I tried to solve the problem in the following way:

```
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(a) %>% 
  mutate(number_acc = count(b == 'acc'), 
         number_rej = count(b == 'rej'),
         number_con = count(b == 'con'))
```

However, i get an error message that the method "count" cannot be applied to objects of the class "logical".

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try to use sum, instead of count. Or simply `as.data.frame.matrix(table(df))` ?

Comment: And you need summarise, not mutate.

Comment: Possible duplicate, related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40266062/680068

Comment: Thank you very much. A small problem remains when I use sum instead of count: I get a single row for each combination of variable a and b but i want to have variable a only once in the new dataframe.

Comment: Perfect it works with summarise! Thank you again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tabyl` function from the janitor package:

Your data:

```
a <- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4)
b <- c("acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej", "con","acc", "rej", "con", "acc", "rej")

df <- data.frame(a,b)
```

Summarize grouping by count:

```
library(janitor)
data_summary <- tabyl(df, a, b)
data_summary

# a acc con rej
# 1   2   1   2
# 2   2   2   1
# 3   1   2   2
# 4   2   1   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way:
We could use `pivot_wider` with `names_glue` after `count`:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  count(a,b) %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    names_from = b,
    values_from = n,
    names_glue = "{b}_{'number'}"
  )
```

```
      a acc_number con_number rej_number
  <dbl>      <int>      <int>      <int>
1     1          2          1          2
2     2          2          2          1
3     3          1          2          2
4     4          2          1          2
```

Comment: Perfect! I just asked myself how to do this with counts. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To make the existing code to work, we need to *summarise* instead of *mutate*, and *sum* instead of *count*:

```
df %>%
  group_by(a) %>% 
  summarise(number_acc = sum(b == 'acc'), 
            number_rej = sum(b == 'rej'),
            number_con = sum(b == 'con'))

# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#       a number_acc number_rej number_con
#   <dbl>      <int>      <int>      <int>
# 1     1          2          2          1
# 2     2          2          1          2
# 3     3          1          2          2
# 4     4          2          2          1
```

But there are better ways of doing this, for example see answers at:

- [Frequency count of two column in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879551)
- [dplyr : how to get two-way tables with marginal proportions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40266062)
- [Count multiple columns and group by in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44508582)